# How to install just the Developer Command Prompt for VS2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

Is there any way to install just the Developer Command Prompt for VS2015 without installing VS 2015? I have a server where I need to install a service using the command prompt "installutil Service.exe" and I don't want to install the entire visual studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`InstallUtil` is installed as part of the .Net Framework.  The developer command prompts simply add values to the `PATH` variable to make the command prompt resolve the proper binaries.

If you want to run install util, just use the full path:

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe`
`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe`